# Can't get sync with SVN to work to put a directory under version control

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoise-svn

I've created a directory on our SVN server and added a local directory with my project to it. It got uploaded and seems to be OK.

However, I didn't get those cute green (or any others) icons on the file. So I clicked on the project's directory and used "checkout". **That** wasn't good because I've downloaded ALL of the repository.

How can I synchronize my uploaded directory with it's corresponding directory on the server? (It's probably something easy that I've forgot to check in or so...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "Checkout" is correct, but you have to select the directory you want instead of the repository root.

Comment: How can I do that? I only have the option of "checkout", no "checkout from..." or such.

Comment: Oh, wait, I think I've found it. You mean that I should open the repo browser and **from there** do a checkout to my local directory, right? Please say "yes", because I'm so proud I've found it... Now I have "SVN update" and "SVN commit" options in the directory. :)

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, choose "Checkout" in an empty directoy and then select a source directory from the repository.

Comment: +1 for a nice follow-up reply. In this case I had the stuff on my local computer **first** and wanted to **upload them** (which I did successfully). **Then** I got confused because the add-ons to the icons didn't show up.